# Pass the bound object type to a converter?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that changes its ItemsSource during run-time.
I need to pass the current object type to a Converter.

Basically:
// dgDisplay - datagrid

```
public class Foo
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public string Data {get; set;}
}

// Property names are different
public class Bar
{
   public int Code {get; set;}
   public string OtherData {get; set;}
}

// Later...

List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo> { new Foo() { Id="ABC", Data = "data1" }}
List<Bar> barList = new List<Bar> { new Bar() { Code=3, OtherData = "data2" }}


if (condition)
    this.dgDisplay.ItemsSource = fooList;
else
    this.dgDisplay.ItemsSource = barList;
```

What I want is to pass Foo or Bar types to the converter in the datadrid in my XAML:
(what should I put here (instead of ????) to get not only the property name, but the item type (Foo or Bar) as well?

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding ConverterParameter=????, Converter={StaticResource PropertyDescriptionConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: How about `value.GetType()` in the Convert method?

Comment: @Clemens, that's what I tried, but without ConverterParameter the converter gets simply a System.String with a property name.

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of struggle, simply used a workaround to get exactly what I wanted using the AutoGeneratingColumn event:

```
private void DgRefTable_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;
    object src = dg.ItemsSource;
    Type type = src.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(e.Column.Header.ToString(), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (property.IsDefined(typeof(RTFieldAttribute), true))
    {
        e.Column.Header = ((RTFieldAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RTFieldAttribute), true)[0]).HeaderText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a template selector for the different types.

This example is for itemscontrol but i'm sure it can be made to work here too.

```
       <ItemsControl.Resources>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:Foo}">
            <Grid>
              Create Template you want, bindings etc. for FOO
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type namespace:Bar}">
            <Grid>
              Create Template you want, bindings etc. for Bar
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
```